# ESXI 7.0: can't label disk as SSD

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've got free ESXI 7.0 U3 installed on Dell R340. There are 4 physical disks Toshiba SSD PX05SMB040 in RAID 5 (1 virtual disk) controlled with PERC H730. Local disk is my boot disk i.e. I don't have seperate disk for ESXI. ESXI sees the disk as non-SSD which I can't change to SSD. So far I have:

1. Updated the PERC controller to the compatible one (https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=34852)
2. Run the command in SSH (https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2013188):

`esxcli storage nmp satp rule add --satp VMW_SATP_LOCAL --device naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11 --"option enable_ssd"`

Rebooted ESXI and run the commands:

`esxcli storage core claiming unclaim --type=device --device naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11`

`esxcli storage core claimrule load`

`esxcli storage core claimrule run`

`esxcli storage core claiming reclaim -d naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11`

but the datastore keeps showing Non-SSD type. The second command i.e. `esxcli storage core claiming unclaim --type=device --device naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11` returned message "Unable to unclaim all requested paths. Some paths were busy or were the last path to an in use device".

3. Checked:

`esxcli storage nmp satp rule list | grep enable_ssd` returns "VMW_SATP_LOCAL naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11 enable_ssd user".

`esxcli storage core device list -d naa.6006016015301d00167ce6e2ddb3de11 | grep SSD` returns "Is SSD: false".

`esxcli storage nmp device list` doesn't return any device but command `esxcli storage hpp device list` returns the disk.

What else can I do to fix it?

Thank you,
Przemek

Comment: is the server running at your home?

Comment: It is not. Why are asking?

Comment: because Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow. and afaik is the R340 a EOL Product iirc

Answer (score 0):

Do you use dell custom iso to install your server? Which 7.0 u3 version are you using (build number)? Did you try with another 7.0 release? On dell support matrix it's said that support 7.0u2
https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ie/vmware-esxi-7.x/vmware_7.0.x_vsphere_compmatrix_pub/dell-emc-poweredge-serverscompatibility-matrix?guid=guid-542042f7-599c-4721-8d3d-77a33f6e07d3
What about server firmware, is up to date?